# Linq many to many selection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables with many to many relationship, in a post-detail page I want to show related posts, the related posts are the post that have at least a category of current post.
[image: The Tables]
How can I select related posts of current post?
I tried with this code , but it's not what I want:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult GetRelatedPost(int id)
    {
        var relatedposts =
            _db.Posts.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title, x.Slug, x.Image, x.IsActive,x.PostType,x.PostCategories })
                .Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Id != id && x.PostCategories.Intersect(_db.PostCategories).Any())
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(20)
                .ToList();
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I solve my problem with this code:

```
            var posts =
            _db.Posts.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title, x.Slug, x.Image, x.IsActive,x.PostType,x.PostCategories })
                .Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Id != id && x.PostCategories.Intersect(_db.PostCategories.Where(y=>y.Posts.Any(p => p.Id==id))).Any())
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(20)
                .ToList();
```

**Is it the best way?**

Comment: Perhaps it's as easy as post.Categories.SelectMany(Posts); select your main post and include .Categories.Posts if you want to eager load them.

Comment: @AlexPaven How can I do it? please help me more

Comment: Ok keeping the projection I was thinking something like .Where(x => x.Categories.Any(c => c.Posts.Any(p => p.Id == id))). It's entirely possible the generated SQL won't be ideal though, you'd have to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I solve my problem with this code:

```
        var posts =
        _db.Posts.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title, x.Slug, x.Image, x.IsActive,x.PostType,x.PostCategories })
            .Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Id != id && x.PostCategories.Intersect(_db.PostCategories.Where(y=>y.Posts.Any(p => p.Id==id))).Any())
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(20)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to select the primary key of the PostCatagories during the intersect:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult GetRelatedPost(int id)
{
    var relatedposts =
        _db.Posts.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title, x.Slug, x.Image, x.IsActive,x.PostType,x.PostCategories })
            .Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Id != id && x.PostCategories.Select(y => y.Id).Intersect(_db.PostCategories.Select(y => y.Id)).Any())
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(20)
            .ToList();
}).Any())
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(20)
            .ToList();
}
```